# Coroutines: Is there a way to block multiple executions and notify them all?

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I've been trying to implement a `wait` & `notifyAll` system like I used to do in Java. Main idea is to make multiple functions call to wait for a signal and continue their execution.

The following test case wraps the intended implementation:

```
@Test
fun blocking_multiple_shouldReturnOne() {
    var valueOne : Int? = null
    var valueTwo : Int? = null
    var valueThree : Int? = null
    var valueFour : Int? = null

    val threadManager = ThreadManager()

    threadManager.startBlocking { 
        valueOne = 1
    }

    threadManager.startBlocking {
        valueTwo = 1
    }

    threadManager.startBlocking {
        valueThree = 1
    }

    threadManager.startBlocking {
        valueFour = 1
    }

    threadManager.startAndNotifyAll {
        valueOne = 0
        valueTwo = 0
        valueThree = 0
        valueFour = 0
    }

    assertTrue("startBlocking wasn't executed right after notify all", valueOne == 1)
    assertTrue("startBlocking wasn't executed right after notify all", valueTwo == 1)
    assertTrue("startBlocking wasn't executed right after notify all", valueThree == 1)
    assertTrue("startBlocking wasn't executed right after notify all", valueFour == 1)
}
```

Is there a way to do this using Coroutines in Kotlin? So far no luck researching.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. Make all your functions suspendable and then call all of them from launch block.
It will be like this

```
suspend fun fun1() {
  println("some async 1")
}

suspend fun fun2() {
  println("some async 2")
}

suspend fun fun3() {
  println("some async 3")
}

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
    fun1()
    fun2()
    fun3()
}
```

The result will be

```
some async 1
some async 2
some async 3
```

Comment: Seems to me that this won't have the desired effect since you're calling them within the same `launch` scope consecutively. Also, `suspend` functions can't be called outside a `context`. I will take a better look soon as I have time and I wasn't the one who voted down btw..

Comment: I just can't understand why my answer is voted down)) I think you can get desired effect with suspendable functions. You can use coroutine channels as well in this case. Hope you will  find optimal solution!